# ONVIF Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'GetStatus' -> The string '1532531507' is not a valid AllXsd value

Tags: c#, xml, onvif

**CONTEXT :**

I'm making a c# windows form app that communicates to ONVIF cameras using the wsdls given on the onvif site.

https://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl/media.wsdl

and

https://onvif.org/onvif/ver20/ptz/wsdl/ptz.wsdl

I am able to get profiles on the camera, send PTZ action and more, but when I try to get the status of the `ptzClient` I created, I get the error:

```
Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'GetStatus'
```

I looked in the innerException of this error to find:

```
The string '1532531507' is not a valid AllXsd value.
```

Here's how I create my ptzClient:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
var commonEncoding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement
                {
                    MessageVersion = MessageVersion.CreateVersion(EnvelopeVersion.Soap12, AddressingVersion.None)
                };
var commonBinding = new HttpTransportBindingElement
                {
                    AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Digest
                };
var commonCustomBinding = new CustomBinding(commonEncoding, commonBinding);
var commonPasswordDigestBehavior = new PasswordDigestBehavior(userName, password);
var ptzEndpointAddress = new EndpointAddress($"http://{cameraAddress}/onvif/ptz");
ptzClient = new PTZClient(commonCustomBinding, ptzEndpointAddress);
ptzClient.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(commonPasswordDigestBehavior);
```

The error happens when calling this line of code:

```
var p = ptzClient.GetStatus(profile.token);
```

When I go see my xml request and its corresponding xml response in wireshark, I see that there is no error :
[image]

**QUESTION :**

How can I manage to make this call without getting these errors?

There isn't much I can change...

It seems that the problem is from the date format, but I don't see a way to change this format.

Comment: I can see that these `UtcTime`, `PanTilt` and `Zoom` values make no sense... Maybe that the camera I'm trying to have access to isn't supporting this call..

Answer (score 0):

To Know whether the camera device supports PTZ, you can call GetCapabilities on device service.

The GetCapabilities list includes references to the addresses (XAddr) of the service(in your case it is PTZ service) implementing the interface operations in the category. If PTZ service is not listed in GetCapabilities list then PTZ is not supported by your device.

GetStatus api just returns PTZ status for the Node in the selected profile.

There are ONVIF test tools available to test your camera on windows platform to easy the development.
http://www.happytimesoft.com/products/onvif-client/index.html

Comment: The problem isn't about knowing if my camera supports PTZ, I can already move my camera arround! (:  It's just that when calling `GetStatus`, I get errors... I wanted to use this info to know what was the state/position of my camera, but as I said in the comments of the post, the returned values are wrong/make no sense... I find strange that my Profile S ONVIF camera doesn't support this call.. Anyways, thanks for your help! I'll try out this tool for sure. I normally use the [OnvifDeviceManager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/onvifdm/) to test my cameras, but one more tool will be usefull!