# Android ONVIF - Internal Server Error when trying to retrieve profiles from ONVIF IP camera

Tags: android, kotlin, android-things, onvif

I'm currently building an Android Things application that communicates with an ONVIF IP camera following [this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FlPYcgj6UdU&t=489s) 
 I can talk to the camera and I can get services and device information but when I try to retrieve profiles, it responds with `D/RESPONSE: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=500, message=Internal Server Error`

What would cause this response?

**onCreate**

```
currentDevice = OnvifDevice("192.168.1.5","admin","password")
currentDevice.listener = this
currentDevice.getServices()
Log.d("REQUEST", "Get services");
```

**requestPerformed**

```
override fun requestPerformed(response: OnvifResponse) {
        //method called when response is received from camera

        Log.d("RESPONSE", response.parsingUIMessage);

        if (response.request.type == OnvifRequest.Type.GetServices) {

            Log.d("REQUEST", "Get device information");
            currentDevice.getDeviceInformation()
        }
        else if (response.request.type == OnvifRequest.Type.GetDeviceInformation) {

            Log.d("REQUEST", "Get profiles");
            currentDevice.getProfiles()
        }
        else if (response.request.type == OnvifRequest.Type.GetProfiles) {

            Log.d("REQUEST", "Get stream URI");
            currentDevice.mediaProfiles.firstOrNull()?.let {
                currentDevice.getStreamURI(it)
            }
        }
        else if (response.request.type == OnvifRequest.Type.GetStreamURI) {

            Log.d("REQUEST", "Get get video stream");
            currentDevice.rtspURI?.let { uri ->

                val surfaceView = findViewById<SurfaceView>(R.id.surfaceView)

                vlcVideoLibrary = VlcVideoLibrary(this, this, surfaceView)
                vlcVideoLibrary?.play(uri)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is internal error in your server API not client side

Comment: Okay, so the error is in the device running my app? Not the IP camera?

Comment: i think ip camera .did you pass correct  values for ip camera?

Comment: Yeah correct IP, username and password. I have tested this by inputting an incorrect password where I received 400 Bad Request and no camera device information

Comment: then check with other device

Comment: sometimes, the problem isn't with the code you wrote, but with the device/camera you're using... I had a problem with one of my camera... It wasn't returning a valid response when asked for its status. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51523249/onvif-error-in-deserializing-body-of-reply-message-for-operation-getstatus) I would suggest you to look for any camera software update. If this still doesn't work, I would suggest to try with another device as @sasikumar said.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the problem isn't with the code you wrote, but with the device/camera you're using... I had a problem with one of my camera... It wasn't returning a valid response when asked for its status. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51523249/onvif-error-in-deserializing-body-of-reply-message-for-operation-getstatus)

I would suggest you to look for any camera software update. If this still doesn't work, I would suggest to try with another device as @sasikumar said.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I will try with another device of another manufacturer and see what the result is.